# node.js MySQL connection not established - only when using XAMPP

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to establish a MySQL connection with my node.js server, but when I do, I get the following error:

```
F:\Programmering\nodejs-server>node dbConnection.js
F:\Programmering\nodejs-server\dbConnection.js:10
  if (err) throw err;
           ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (F:\Programmering\nodejs-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\
protocol\Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (F:\Programmering\nodejs-server\node_modules\mysql\lib
\protocol\Protocol.js:52:23)
    at Connection.connect (F:\Programmering\nodejs-server\node_modules\mysql\lib
\Connection.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Programmering\nodejs-server\dbConnection.js:9:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
```

I've tried using other ports, but still same error message. When I use XAMPP, and start MySQL service, it connects fine. These are the messages when I install mysql using npm:

```
F:\Programmering\nodejs-server>npm install mysql
npm WARN nodejs-server@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ mysql@2.15.0
added 11 packages in 7.809s
```

I have been using the w3schools tutorial. This is my code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "myusername",
  password: "mypassword"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help! Thank you!

Comment: You already figured out that  when you `[...] start MySQL service, it connects fine.`. So why do you think that `mysql.createConnection` should be able to connect to mysql it the service is not running?

Comment: Ah thank you for your response! I thought `mysql.createConnection()` starts the service :D. Is it fine to use XAMPP to run a MySQL service? Or is something else recommended when using node.js?